# Toolbar jump when stop NestedScrollView scroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am experiencing a weird toolbar scrolling issue. After I scroll the toolbar up and while it's moving upward with inertia (fling), I try to stop the child view by touching on the NestedScrollView and the toolbar is automatically expanded. (both views jump back as you can see toward the end of the attached gif.)

My layout is pretty straightforward. It's based on Android Studio project template.

Any thought of how to make the behavior looks more natural?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: scroll]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a CollapsingToolbarLayout widget inside AppBarLayout. so when you scroll down/up the Toolbar/Appbar will collapse/expand smoothly.

The whole appbarlayout should be changed to:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarTitleText"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/article_keylines"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/md_keylines"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: thanks but i'm still seeing the jump when set the height to 400dp as in my requirement and also i don't want the collapsing effect